# how to disable group hover on click of link on mobile website

Tags: html, hover, tailwind-css

Hi I am using the following code to display a link. It has a custom group hover that works perfectly on hover supported devices. Only on touch screen when you click on the link, the div that covers the background gets retained until I click any where on the screen. I have used different states such as active, visited  to hide the opacity but none seems to be working for this case.

```
<div class="group relative md:max-w-md">
  <a href="">
    <div class="absolute -inset-y-2 -inset-x-4 z-0 rounded-3xl bg-gray-200/50 opacity-0 transition group-hover:opacity-100 dark:bg-gray-700/50"></div>
    <div class="z-10 flex flex-col space-y-1 group-hover:relative">
      <p class="text-justify tracking-normal">This is the link</p>
      <div class="text-accent flex items-center text-sm font-medium">
        Know more
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" class="mt-0.5 ml-1 h-4 w-4 stroke-current">
          <path d="M6.75 5.75 9.25 8l-2.5 2.25" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can check out the code in tailwind play

[tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sVd3hniP7V)

Adding GIF for reference. see the part where I use back button gesture and the hover stays.

[image: GIF]

Comment: The issue is not reproducible for me in the tailwind play.

Comment: you can go to the tailwind play link in mobile and click on the link. for back button enabled devices in android when you click the back button, the hover indent remains even though the navigated to something else.  only in android phone with back button I am facing this.

Comment: Added gif to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

To disable that on mobile, add breakpoint prefix to class `group`

This is just an example, you can adjust to the breakpoint prefix you need

```html
<div class="md:group relative md:max-w-md">
  ...
</div>
```

Hope this help